# Java, ProcessBuilder for python script with python module (numpy)

Tags: java, python, numpy, processbuilder

I want to use ProcessBuilder to execute a python script. I can execute this script with the command "python3 myscript.py" without any problem. But When I use ProcessBuilder in java, I get an error from my script :

```
import numpyImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

numpy is the module that I want to use, but I can't find it.
This is the way I call my script :

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python3","main.py","-rd ",selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your python path:

run in your terminal: "which python3"

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("your/python/path/python3","main.py","-rd ",selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
```